# Meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning

Context - describing the interior of a hospital:

> 老人が六人収容されている部屋の廊下側、窓がなく、カーテンで仕切られているせいもあり外の景色が一切見えない気の塞ぐスペースだ。

老人が六人収容されている部屋の廊下側、窓がなく...

Does it mean there are no windows facing the corridor (as seen from inside a hospital room)?

...カーテンで仕切られている...

Is the hospital room separated into six spaces (for six patients) by curtains?

Is it also implied there are no windows at all (so that 外の景色が一切見えない)?

A bigger chunk of text, in case it helps:

翌日の朝から母とともに病院を訪れ、会社に行く母を駅まで送りまた病院へ戻った健斗は、暗い病室の隅に腰掛けていた。老人が六人収容されている部屋の廊下側、窓がなく、カーテンで仕切られているせいもあり外の景色が一切見えない気の塞ぐスペースだ。酸素吸入や点滴に心電図といった全身チューブだらけで眠っている祖父が目覚めたら、自宅の北向きの部屋より窮屈なほぼ自然光の入らない空間に、死にたくなるだろう。

Comment: その引用文は主語が書かれていないようなので、もう１つ前の文章も書いてもらえますか？ (「老人が六人収容されている部屋の廊下側」の後に、「は」はないんですよね？)

Comment: ちょっとコンテキストを追加みました...あらためてチェックしましたけど、「は」はたしかにないようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。主語は、「祖父が入院しているスペース」/「祖父のベッドがある位置」みたいですね。「祖父が寝ている場所は、老人が6人収容されている部屋の廊‌‌​​下側で、(だから)窓がなくて、カーテンで仕切られているから外の景色が見えないスペースだ。」(Grandfather's bed is in the corridor's side of the room, (so) there's no windows, and you can't see outside from there cos the room is partitioned by curtains) って感じで。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the hospital room is separated into some spaces for patients by curtains and the spaces facing the corridor don't have windows.The spaces facing the outside may have windows but the both sides of the spaces between them are curtain.

Does it mean there are no windows facing the corridor? My answer is Yes.

Is the hospital room separated into six spaces (for six patients) by curtains? My answer is that only this content can't be judged it but the room is separated into more than six spaces because six persons have already been warded.

Is it also implied there are no windows at all? My answer is that only this content can't be judged it because the spaces facing the outside may have windows and if there are windows there but if the curtains is closed, the person who stay the spaces facing the corridor can't see outside.

[image]